# mysqli fetch array expects one parameter to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having trouble with my `mysqli_fetch_array()` code. I have swapped and changed variables plenty of times to figure out why it won't work. Essentially I need it to access my database and find how many rows fit a particular criteria and return the value. Any insight on what I can do to go about getting my `mysqli_fetch_array()` function to work?

Thanks.

```
<html>
<?php
$uname = "";
$pword = "";
$errorMessage = "";

function quote_smart($handle, $value) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }

    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        $value = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($handle, $value) . "'";
    }

    return $value;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$pword = $_POST['password'];

$uname = htmlspecialchars($uname);
$pword = htmlspecialchars($pword);

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
$db = mysqli_select_db($con, "users");

if ($db) {

    $uname = quote_smart($con, $uname);
    $pword = quote_smart($con, $pword);

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE L1 = $uname AND L2 = md5($pword)";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $SQL);
    $num_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);

    if ($result) {
        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
            header ("Location: home.php");
        }
        else {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = "";
            header ("Location: regpage.php");
        }   
    }
    else {
        $errorMessage = "Error logging on";
    }

mysqli_close($con);

}

else {
    $errorMessage = "Error logging on";
}

}
?>
</html>
```

The main code I am having an issue with is:

```
   $num_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Every time I run it, I get this error message:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE L1 = '".$uname."' AND L2 = '".md5($pword)."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $SQL)or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

use mysqli_error and pass connection as argument in it

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "stackoverflow");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $SQL)or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

**Tested Code**

```
<?php
    $uname = "";
    $pword = "";
    $errorMessage = "";

    function quote_smart($handle, $value)
    {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }

        if (!is_numeric($value))
        {
            $value = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($handle, $value) . "'";
        }
        return $value;
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {
        $uname = $_POST['username'];
        $pword = $_POST['password'];

        $uname = htmlspecialchars($uname);
        $pword = htmlspecialchars($pword);

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","stackoverflow");

        if ($con)
        {
            $uname = quote_smart($con, $uname);
            $pword = quote_smart($con, $pword);

            $SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ".$uname." AND password = ".$pword."";

            $result = mysqli_query($con, $SQL);
            $num_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);

            if ($result)
            {
                if ($num_rows > 0)
                {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
                    header ("Location: home.php");
                    exit;
                }
                else
                {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['login'] = "";
                    header ("Location: regpage.php");
                    exit;
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                $errorMessage = "Error logging on";
            }
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
        else
        {
            $errorMessage = "Error logging on";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: When I try your code, I get this error code: "Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in"

Comment: you need to pass connection string inside that..

Comment: So I passed the connection into it, and I get this now: "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in". I am assuming I need to pass through an INT?

Comment: @teepleb make sure you are passing right connection into all query..

Comment: I double checked and I have the right connection going into all my queries. I am still getting this: "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in". And currently my line of code is
    $num_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

Comment: @teepleb try mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)

Comment: "Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given" I am still getting this error. Do I have to use mysqli_result inside there?

Comment: yes but you are already passing $result so its not needed..add all code in question

Comment: That is what I figured, I am lost at what to do. Is it bad coding on my part? Everything in the OP is my login script. I don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: I added it to the main post, I can't get code comments to work here.

Comment: @teepleb i have updated my answer and it working fine for me...it successfully redirect to home.php and echo session login 1 inside home.php

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I will compare codes and try to see if I can figure out why mine didn't work. But thanks a lot!

Comment: @teepleb may be because you were using mysqli_select_db...welcome already +1 for question

Answer (score 0):

`$num_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);` this results array of data not number of rows

to get number of rows use `mysqli_num_rows($result)`

OR

`$num_rows = count(mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM));`

Answer (score 0):

The **md5()** is **php** function & not **mysql** function. In your case you are using it like it is mysql function . Just replace your query by this:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE L1 = $uname AND L2 = '".md5($pword)."' ";
```